# How to find several items from the same array in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In the collection "friendship" I would like to find all Bart's friends that are 10. The $elemMatch query only returns the first matching element of the array : I only get Milhouse. How can I get Milhouse and Martin ?

```
{   name:'Bart',
    age:10
    friends:[
       {    name:'Milhouse',
            age:10
       },
       {    name:'Nelson',
            age:11
       },
       {    name:'Martin',
            age:10
       }
   ]
},
{   name:'Lisa',
    age:8
    friends:[
       ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any queries yourself first? Could you please post them?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for this task (especially [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator):

```
db.friendship.aggregate([
    { $match: { name: "Bart" } },
    { $unwind: "$friends" },
    { $match: { "friends.age": 10 } }
]);
```